# How to get a unique and constant id of a view

Tags: android, view

I need to have an id/name which is related to views in my app, the id/name will keep constant across different builds and each id/name will be unique for the specific view.

I wanted to used view.getId(), but this may change between two builds.
Another choice is to use tag: view.getTag(), but this need extra operation view.setTag(),which is not my choice.

So is it possible to find such id/name and I can get through view object?

Comment: The numerical ID might change between builds, but the resource name - i.e., `android:id="@+id/whatever"`, `R.id.whatever` - would be constant. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: You can set Id from code: View#setId() form XML imho not posible

Comment: @MikeM. is it unique  across app? and Can I get it from view object? such as view.getResourceName()... I don't think it works

Comment: @LunaVulpo sorry I don't want any extra operations before I can get that as I said in the post

Comment: "is it unique across app?" - Yes. "Can I get it from view object?" -  `getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId())`, or `getResourceName()`, if you want the full name, with the package and type.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks it helps. But for programmatically created view, this does not work, this is the only limit. Please wrote an answer and I can accept it

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean to do that, or the overall requirements, but you can guarantee unique IDs at runtime by defining them in your `<resources>` - `<item type="id" name="whatever" />` - which you could then assign to a `View` instantiated directly, with `setId()`. Alternatively, you can create a layout with your `View` and its ID, and inflate that at runtime. Anyhoo, if all you really needed was how to get the resource name for a `View` ID, I can just close this as a duplicate, since that's been answered before.

Comment: @MikeM. what I mean is: if the view is created by this way: View view = new View(...); your method is now working, for I don't want to setId for that.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by "instantiated directly". Anyway, if you don't set an ID for a `View`, it just doesn't have one. I'm not sure why you don't want to use `setId()`, but that's exactly what gets called when a `View` is inflated from a layout. Really, it sounds like you might be too tightly coupling your data to the UI. You shouldn't need to rely on `View` IDs for your data model.

Comment: @MikeM. I just found that the "setId" only accept int param. So is there a way that I can set a resource entry name even if the view is created at runtime?

Comment: The resource names for IDs must be defined at compile time. As I mentioned above, you can define an ID with something like `<item type="id" name="whatever" />` in your `<resources>`. You can then call `setId(R.id.whatever)` on a dynamically created `View`. If you're asking if you can dynamically create resource names, then no. If you just want to stick a name on a `View`, look at the `setTag()`/`getTag()` methods.